# Bash - Rename all files that contain a given regex pattern

Tags: bash, regex

I have some files in a directory that that all contain either the string "HG-U133A", or "HG-U133B". I'd like to write a script that can go through all the files in the directory and rename all the "HG-U133A" files with an "A_" prefix, and all "HG-U133B" files with a "B_" prefix.

So if these are the files in my directory

```
> grep "HG-U133[AB]" *
fileA.txt: HG-U133A
fileB.txt: HG-U133A
fileC.txt: HG-U133B
fileD.txt: HG-U133A
fileE.txt: HG-U133B
```

I'd like to write a script that can rename these files to

```
> ls
A_fileA.txt
A_fileB.txt
B_fileC.txt
A_fileD.txt
B_fileE.txt
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a portable solution that doesn't fall into the [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

```
for file in *; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  grep -q -- HG-U133A "$file" && { mv -- "$file" "A_$file"; continue; }
  grep -q -- HG-U133B "$file" && mv -- "$file" "B_$file"
done
```

Notes:

- `*` doesn't match dotfiles, but you used it in your `grep` invocation, so I assume the behavior fits you or you know how to change it.
- `*` does match directories. Your `grep` was invoked without options that might make it process directories. The script skips anything that is not a regular file and the main purpose of this is to skip directories and not bother running `grep` for them (which would fail anyway).
- Double dash (`--`) is explained here: [What does `--` (double-dash) mean? (also known as “bare double dash”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) It's in case any of the filenames starts with a dash. If we used `./*` instead of `*` we wouldn't need it.
- You said "either … or …", I interpret this as "for a given file at most one string will match". Therefore `continue` after the first `grep`. It's there to not call the second `grep` in vain.
- If you expect many files with `HG-U133B` and only few with `HG-U133A` then consider testing for `HG-U133B` first.

Advantages:

- portability,
- robustness (the code should work well regardless of file names).

Disadvantage:

- spawning at least one `grep` process per regular file is far from being optimal; this may slow things down if there are more than few files to inspect.

Answer (score -1):

The following commands in `bash` will do it:

```
for file in `grep -l HG-U133A *` ; do mv "$file" "A_$file" ; done
for file in `grep -l HG-U133B *` ; do mv "$file" "B_$file" ; done
```

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed: Did this work for you?

Comment: Yes. it did. Thank you. Although, the other answer seems to be a little more robust.

Comment: If you used it and it solved your problem, in spite of not handling cases that you didn't have, should it not get at least an upvote?